# pandas data frame: Find consecutive values and ignoring gaps of certain size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggeling with hourly precipitation data like e.g.

```
index=pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365*24, freq='H')
precipitation_indicator=np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(365*24,))
precipitation_sum=np.random.ranf((365*24,))*6*precipitation_indicator

prec_dataH=pd.DataFrame(data={'prec_ind':precipitation_indicator, prec_sum':precipitation_sum},index=index)
```

I want do define rain events if there is precipitation in consecutive time points, but also if there is a gap of a certain length within one event. 
I solved this with an rolling window by using the following code

```
gap_to_ignore=1  
prec_dataH['event_ind']=prec_dataH['prec_ind'].rolling(window=(1+2*gap_to_ignore), center=True).max().dropna()
```

By doing so I get an event_ind of 1 whenever there is precipitation and also for breaks of 2 hours within the rainevent, but also for the timestamp 1 hour in advance and 1 hour after the rainevent. I now want to remove this 1 hour in advance and after the rainevent. I managed this by

1.) giving an continous number to each change occouring in event_ind

```
prec_dataH['event_no'] = (prec_dataH['event_ind'].shift(1) != prec_dataH['event_ind']).astype(int).cumsum()
```

2.) assigning dry periods a NaN value for event_no

```
def reorder_eventNumbers_dryStart (event_numbers):
    if event_numbers % 2 !=0:
        return event_numbers/2
    else:
        return np.NaN

def reorder_eventNumbers_rainStart (event_numbers):
    if event_numbers % 2 ==0:
        return event_numbers/2
    else:
        return np.NaN

if prec_dataH.ix[1, 'event_ind']==1.:

    prec_dataH['event_no']=prec_dataH['event_no'].apply(reorder_eventNumbers_rainStart)
elif prec_dataH.ix[1, 'event_ind']==0.:
    prec_dataH['event_no']=prec_dataH['event_no'].apply(reorder_eventNumbers_dryStart)
```

3.) Groupby the event_no, iterating through the groups and assigning NaN values to the values 1 hour in advance and 1 hour after the precipitation event and finaly concat the groups to a new DataFrame.

This is quite time intensive and thereby a SettingWighCopyWarning occures and I don't understand why this occures.

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

Here is the code I use:

```
rainEvents=prec_dataH.groupby('event_no')

groups=[]
for name, group in rainEvents:
    group.ix[0:gap_to_ignore,'event_ind'] =np.NaN
    group.ix[0:gap_to_ignore,'event_no'] =np.NaN
    group.ix[-gap_to_ignore:, 'event_ind']=np.NaN
    group.ix[-gap_to_ignore:,'event_no'] =np.NaN
    groups.append(group)

rainEvents_corrected=pd.concat(groups)
```

So how can I avoid this SettingWithCopyWarning and how can I make my code more efficient??

Thanks in advance,
Axel

Comment: Add `group = group.copy()` as the first line in the `for` loop. That gets rids of the `SettingWithCopyWarning ` and speeds up your computation.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this speeds the computation up a lot. But is there any better way to get out a DataFrame from the groupby object or applying a filter instead of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `group = group.copy()` as the first line in the `for` loop. That gets rid of the `SettingWithCopyWarning` and speeds up your computation by a factor of ~60.

```
def approach1():
    rainEvents=prec_dataH.groupby('event_no')

    groups=[]
    for name, group in rainEvents:
        group.ix[0:gap_to_ignore,'event_ind'] =np.NaN
        group.ix[0:gap_to_ignore,'event_no'] =np.NaN
        group.ix[-gap_to_ignore:, 'event_ind']=np.NaN
        group.ix[-gap_to_ignore:,'event_no'] =np.NaN
        groups.append(group)

    rainEvents_corrected=pd.concat(groups)


def approach2():
    rainEvents=prec_dataH.groupby('event_no')

    groups=[]
    for name, group in rainEvents:
        group = group.copy()
        group.ix[0:gap_to_ignore,'event_ind'] =np.NaN
        group.ix[0:gap_to_ignore,'event_no'] =np.NaN
        group.ix[-gap_to_ignore:, 'event_ind']=np.NaN
        group.ix[-gap_to_ignore:,'event_no'] =np.NaN
        groups.append(group)

    rainEvents_corrected=pd.concat(groups)

%timeit approach1()    # => 1 loop, best of 3: 1min 29s per loop
%timeit approach2()    # => 1 loop, best of 3: 1.42 s per loop
```

You can avoid the `for` loop by using `.apply()` on your `groupby` object with an appropriate function (which essentially mimics the body of your `for` loop). It seems to provide a 20-30% speedup with respect to the above.

```
def approach3():
    def correct_rainEvents(g):
        g.ix[:gap_to_ignore, ['event_ind', 'event_no']] = np.nan
        g.ix[-gap_to_ignore:, ['event_ind', 'event_no']] = np.nan
        return g

    rainEvents_corrected = (prec_dataH.groupby('event_no')
                                      .apply(correct_rainEvents)
                                      .reset_index(level='event_no', drop=True))

%timeit approach3()    # => 1 loop, best of 3: 1.12 s per loop
```